# Using variable values defined in one file, in files in the same directory

Tags: files, environment-variables, variable-substitution, read

In [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/benqzq/ulcwe) I have a directory named `nwsm`. This directory contains the file `nwsm.sh` that contains a master script (a script that runs other scripts).

The directory also contains a few other files which contain sub-scripts that the master script executes, each one at a time.

In `nwsm.sh` I declare a few variables and these variables should eventually be used inside all aforementioned subscripts. Variable expansion in both `nwsm.sh` and subscripts should take place the same way, only in their execution.

---

Note that the directory doesn't contain any other files besides `nwsm.sh` and its sub script files, nor that it should contain other files, at any time in the future.

Variable expansions inside the subscripts should occur with the relevant values defined in `nwsm.sh`, after `nwsm.sh` started to run.

This is the master script in `nwsm.sh` (first the variable declarations with the `read` utility, then the execution of the adjacent files):

```
#!/bin/bash
domain="$1" && test -z "$domain" && exit 2

read -sp "Please enter DB root password:      " dbrootp_1 && echo
read -sp "Please enter DB root password again:" dbrootp_2 && echo
if [ "$dbrootp_1" != "$dbrootp_2" ]; then echo "Values unmatched" && exit 1 fi

read -sp "Please enter DB user password:      " dbuserp_1 && echo
read -sp "Please enter DB user password again:" dbuserp_2 && echo
if [ "$dbuserp_1" != "$dbuserp_2" ]; then echo "Values unmatched" && exit 1 fi

"$PWD"/tests.sh
"$PWD"/wp-cli.sh
"$PWD"/nginx.sh
"$PWD"/dbstack.sh
"$PWD"/certbot.sh
```

How could I ensure that values defined in `nwsm.sh` will be available to all its counterparts while `.nwsm`, and them, are running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you just want to have the variables visible when the main script runs the other scripts, then you just `export` them:

```
$ cat main.sh 
#!/bin/sh
read foo
export foo
./foo.sh
$ cat foo.sh 
#!/bin/sh
echo "foo is $foo"

$ ./main.sh 
blah
foo is blah
$
```

The other scripts run as subprocesses of the main script, and `export`ed variables get passed to them through the environment. None of this limits the variables to scripts in a particular directory, exported variables are visible to all programs started by the main script. If you want to run some program without passing the variables to them, you'll have to unexport them with `export -n` first. You could also unexport at the start of the other scripts, to avoid them passing the variables on.

Also note that there's no need to clear the variables or unexport them at the end of the main script (or the others). The variables only exist in the memory of the running shell processes, and when the process ends, the variables disappear.

(Passing variables to independent processes, on the other hand, would require saving them to a file or some such.)

---

Of course, another way to achieve almost the same kind of modularization would be to split the program into functions, store them in separate files and `source` those files from the main script. That way, all the variables in the program would be visible to all functions. (Which may or may not be preferable.)

Comment: So much thanks! How do you properly `export` `read` variables? (I have something in mind but ask just in case).

Comment: @user9303970, just `read var; export var;` there's the sample script in the answer. (I don't think there's a flag in `read` to make it export the variables it writes) Or, you could use `set -a` in the beginning to make all modified variables automatically exported but that has a wider effect and is much less explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you export your variables, then at end of your master script, "unset" the variables.

```
unset domain
unset dbrootp_1
unset dbrootp_2
unset dbuserp_1
unset dbuserp_2
```

unset: unset [-f] [-v] [name ...]
    For each NAME, remove the corresponding variable or function.  Given
    the `-v', unset will only act on variables.  Given the`-f' flag,
    unset will only act on functions.  With neither flag, unset first
    tries to unset a variable, and if that fails, then tries to unset a
    function.  Some variables cannot be unset; also see readonly.